# When an email has an embedded image in Gmail, can the sender trace IP?

Tags: email, gmail, privacy

When an email has an embedded image in Gmail, can the sender trace IP of the send to user?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the image is loaded on to your machine as if you were visiting a web page, so your ip will show up in their server logs or script that is monitoring the email e.t.c.

It is the same as with Hotmail, Outlook or anywhere else which is why you usually get a warning when the picture is going to load (and usually blocked by default)

The only pictures that are safe from this sort of thing are the ones that are actually included / attached to the email.

It should be noted that a proxy does not really protect you all the time from this sort of method. More often than not, the reason for attaching a externally linked picture is not to track a ip but just to confirm that the email was received in the first place. The other use is usually just for time-critical content so proxy doesn't really make a difference

Comment: As homestead noted in a comment to another answer, an email address, UUID or other code could be used to correlate successful loading of the image with the intended recipient.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. See this updated answer https://superuser.com/a/931561/31240

Answer (score 3):

Gmail loads images from the source site directly, and does not proxy the connection.

So yes, if the image was hosted on a site controlled by the sender, it is possible for them to see which IPs have connected to load the image. This does not link your IP to your email address unless you're the only person receiving this email. Pretty unlikely.

For web privacy, [use a proxy](http://www.tech-faq.com/setup-proxy-server.shtml).

Comment: It should be noted that a proxy does not really protect you all the time from this sort of method. More often than not, the reason for attaching a externally linked picture is not to track a ip but just to confirm that the email was received in the first place. The other use is usually just for time-critical content so proxy doesn't really make a difference

Comment: but they could prepend my email address in the url to track when I view the image!

Comment: @homestead good call. @Wil very true. I was only concerned about the IP

Answer (score 3):

This has changed between now and the answers from 2009. [According to Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en), images can no longer be used by the sender to obtain the IP address of the recipient:

> Some senders try to use externally linked images in harmful ways, but Gmail takes action to ensure that images are loaded safely. Gmail serves all images through Google’s image proxy servers and transcodes them before delivery to protect you in the following ways:
>
> - **Senders can’t use image loading to get information like your IP address or location.**
> - Senders can’t set or read cookies in your browser.
> - Gmail checks your images for known viruses or malware.
>
> In some cases, **senders may be able to know whether an individual has opened a message with unique image links**. As always, Gmail scans every message for suspicious content and if Gmail considers a sender or message potentially suspicious, images won’t be displayed and you’ll be asked whether you want to see the images.

Just to reiterate that last paragraph: Please note that it is possible (indeed common practice) for the sender to obtain the information on whether or not you opened the email and at what time you opened it. This is a common feature of standard mail services (e.g., Mail Chimp).

Answer (score 1):

These kind of tracking images are often called [web bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug).

Some mail server software (such as [MailScanner](http://www.mailscanner.info/)) can quite accurately tell web bugs from normal images, and then disarm the web bugs by removing or replacing them. But Gmail [does not claim](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/about_privacy.html) to try that, though [a few say](http://www.lesjones.com/2009/07/09/the-disarmed-label-on-gmail-means-the-tracking-web-bug-was-removed/) Gmail in fact does.